# HTML 5 File API uploading a file in browser and saving contents as a string

Tags: javascript, html, html5-filesystem

I want the user to upload a file from their computer onto the browser, and then have the contents of it saved as a string so it can be parsed by the rest of the program. I'm looking at CSV files, but in theory, I'd hope this would work for any file containing some sort of text. This should be all client side. I am not sending anything to the server directly from the uploaded file.

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="files" />
    <br />
    <input type="button" onclick="click()">

    <script>
        var file = this.target;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event){
        window.text = event.target.result;
        };

        reader.readAsText(file);
        console.log(window.text);

        function click(){
            alert(window.text);
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But the console always logs undefined,even after I have selected a file. The onclick function doesn't seem to work either (perhaps because the contents are undefined?)

How do I upload a file with text and save it's contents as a string as a variable?

**Edit 1:**
Someone left a helpful answer but I guess deleted it. I was able to better follow some of the information posted [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=kAG5NpkIqxC), which explains how to get the contents of the file, yet I am still having some difficulties. That link explains how to upload a file and then displays an alert containing the file's information, as well as a substring of the contents of the file. 
However, I would like to be able to see the entire file's contents when they are saved in a variable. I changed part of their code to create a global variable that contained what I thought was the file's contents, yet whenever I log it to the console, even after uploading a file, it still logs `undefined`. The onclick alert function also continues to not display.

```
<input type="button" onclick="click()" />
<input type="file" id="fileinput" />
<script>
    function readSingleFile(event) {
    //Retrieve the first (and only!) File from the FileList object
        var file = event.target.files[0]; 

        if (file){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) { 
                window.contents = e.target.result;
                alert( "Got the file.n" 
                    +"name: " + file.name + 
                    + "starts with: " + window.contents.substr(1, window.contents.indexOf("n"))
                );  
            }
            reader.readAsText(file);
        }
        else { 
            alert("Failed to load file");
        }
    };

    document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);

    document.write(window.contents);
    function click(){
        alert(window.contents);
    };
</script>
```

How can I print/log/alert/etc the variable that contains the text, so I can see how to access it later? Despite using a global variable, when I try to run other functions on the string, it says it cannot do so because it is `undefined`.

**Edit 2:** 
With Ray Nicholus's comments, I decided to create a function that copied over the file contents from the onload function into a global variable so it could be used outside the function. Adding the rest of my program code into the onload function would be nearly impossible and require some major reformatting.

```
function makeGlobalText(s){
    window.text = s;
};

function readSingleFile(event) {
        var file = event.target.files[0]; 

        if (file){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) { 
                var contents = e.target.result;
                alert( "Got the file.n" 
                    +"name: " + file.name + 
                    + "starts with: " + contents.substr(1,contents.indexOf("n"))
                );
                makeGlobalText(contents);
            };
            reader.readAsText(file);
        }
        else { 
            alert("Failed to load file");
        }
    };

    document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
```

Yet again, when trying to log the console, print to the screen, or alert with `window.text`after calling `makeGlobalText(contents)` inside the onload function, everything remains undefined or nonresponsive. This time there is likely some trivial problem I am not seeing.

If I make a function that takes in the string from within `onload` and copies it to a global variable, why can't I access that variable outside?

Comment: You have access to the file's contents in your `onload` handler.  Do whatever you want with the file contents inside that function.  Also, remove your call to `document.write`.  `window.contents` will be either undefined or the contents of the previous file when that is executed.

Comment: I need to parse the contents and run it through a bunch of regular expressions that create different arrays that will all be displayed in a certain fashion with AngularJS. I should do _all_ of this in the onload handler? There is no way at all to pull that string out?

Comment: You certainly can't parse the contents before the contents property exists on the `window` object.  The `onload` is updating the value of this property.  If you don't want a large `onload` function, create other functions that you call inside of `onload`.

Answer (score 0):

The script has no context to the file, you are calling the code inline. You should be using a change event or a form submission.

```
var file = this.target;
console.log(file);  //look at what the "target" is
var reader = new FileReader();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example logs very similar to http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html

maybe you should take a look:

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  function readSingleFile(evt) {
  //Retrieve the first (and only!) File from the FileList object
  var f = evt.target.files[0]; 

  if (f) {
    var r = new FileReader();
    r.onload = function(e) { 
        var contents = e.target.result;
      alert( "Got the file.n" 
            +"name: " + f.name + "n"
            +"type: " + f.type + "n"
            +"size: " + f.size + " bytesn"
            + "starts with: " + contents
      );  
    }
    r.readAsText(f);
  } else { 
    alert("Failed to load file");
  }
}

document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
</script>
```

I removed the substring call after the "starts with:" so you can see the whole file

Comment: How could I create a function that saved that content variable as a global variable? Please see my second edit on the question.

Comment: just remove the 'var' keyword before 'contents' and it will be global. But its undefined until you select a file.